# Footnotes not displayed on the correct page

Tags: footnotes

I've used the following code:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,smallroyalvopaper,oldfontcommands]{memoir} 
     
    \usepackage{bm,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,calc,color,times,ragged2e,makeidx,natbib,xpatch}
    \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
    \usepackage[within=chapter]{newfloat}
    \usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
    \usepackage{algorithmic,comment}
    \usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
    \usepackage{wasysym}
    \usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
    \usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}
    \usepackage{MnSymbol}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{anyfontsize}  %% used to tweak fonts in url command 
    \usepackage{refcount}
    \usepackage{footnote}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{sidecap}
    \usepackage{enumitem} 
    \usepackage{flushend}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \newcommand\appshrink{\vspace{-10pt}}
    \newcommand{\km}{\mbox{\,km}}
    \newcommand{\dy}{\mbox{\,d}}
    \newcommand{\gn}{\ensuremath{\,\mathbb{G}}}
    \newcommand{\mmoon}{M_{\!\!\rightmoon}}
    \newcommand{\kg}{\mbox{\,kg}}
    \newcommand{\mearth}{M_\oplus}
    \newcommand{\rmoon}{R_{\!\!\rightmoon}}
    \newcommand{\au}{\,\mbox{au}}
    \newcommand{\yr}{\mbox{\,yr}}
    \newcommand{\msun}{M_\odot}
    \newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
    
    \subsubsection*{Moon}
    
    \appshrink
    
    \begin{savenotes}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{lrl}
    semimajor axis&$a=$&$384\,400\km$ \\
    eccentricity&$e=$&$0.0549$ \\
    inclination&$I=$&$5.15^\circ$ \\
    orbital period&$P=$&$27.322\dy$ \\
    mass parameter\footnote{\label{foot:grail}\cite{will14}.}&$\gn \mmoon=$&$4.902\,80\times
                                10^{12}\mbox{\,m}^3\mbox{\,s}^{-2}$ \\
    mass&$\mmoon=$&$7.345\,79/g\times 10^{22}\kg$\\
    Earth/Moon mass ratio&$\mearth/\mmoon=$ &$81.3005$ \\
    spin period&$P_s=$&$27.322\dy$\\
    obliquity&$\epsilon=$&$6.68^\circ$ \\
    moment of inertia\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{foot:grail}]&$C/(\mmoon\rmoon^2)=$&$0.392\,73$ \\
    quadrupole moment&$J_2=$&$0.000\,203\,22$ \\
    gravitational Love number\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{foot:grail}]&$k_2=$&$0.0242(2)$ \\
    displacement Love number\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{foot:grail}]&$h_2=$&$0.0424(1)$ \\
    mean
    radius\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{foot:grail}]&$\overline R=$&$1\,737.15\km$ \\
    reference radius&$\rmoon=$&$1\,738\km$
    \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \end{savenotes}
    
    \appshrink
    \appshrink
    \appshrink
    
    \subsubsection*{Mars}
    
    \appshrink
    
    \begin{savenotes}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{lrl}
    semimajor axis&$a=$&$1.523\,71\au$ \\
    eccentricity&$e=$&$0.093\,39$ \\
    inclination&$I=$&$1.85^\circ$ \\
    orbital period&$P=$&$686.980\dy=1.880\,85\yr$     \\
    mass parameter\footnote{\label{foot:genova16}\cite{genova16}.}&$\gn M=$&$4.282\,84\times 10^{13}\mbox{\,m}^3\mbox{\,s}^{-2}$ \\
    mass&$M=$&$6.416\,91/g\times 10^{23}\kg$ \\
    Sun/planet mass ratio&$\msun/M=$&$3.098\,71\times10^6$\\
    spin period& $P_s=$&$1.025\,96\dy$ \\
    obliquity&$\epsilon=$&$25.19^\circ$ \\
    moments of inertia\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{foot:genova16}]\footnote{\cite{kon11}.}
                  &$C/(MR_\mathrm{p}^2)=$&$0.3644(5)$ \\
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{$J_2=[C-\half(A+B)]/(MR_\mathrm{p}^2)=$}&
                                                  $0.001\,956\,61$ \\
                                                  \multicolumn{2}{r}{$(B-A)/(MR_\mathrm{p}^2)=$}& $0.000\,252\,43$ \\
       %% see old paper by Bills and James (1999) for normalization
    gravitational Love number\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{foot:genova16}]&
                                                                           $k_2=$&$0.170(1)$ \\
    equatorial radius\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{foot:arch}]&$R_\mathrm{eq}=$&$3\,396.2\km$ \\
    polar radius\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{foot:arch}]&$R_\mathrm{pol}=$&$3\,376\km$ \\
    reference radius&$R_\mathrm{p}=$&$3\,396\km$
    \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \end{savenotes}
    
    
    \end{document}
```

It compiles without error, but footnotes `2` and `3` don't appear on the first page.

Comment: The savenotes environment, as its name implies "saves" all the footnotes inside of it until the environment is finished and then prints them there, so the footnotes aren't being printed until after the longtable is over. What were you trying to accomplish with the savenotes environment?

Comment: @frabjous Thanks, for your hint about `savenotes`, by removing that, my problem solved...

Comment: Please make your comment to the `answer`, I'll approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Copied from comments above.) The savenotes environment, as its name implies, "saves" all the footnotes inside of it until the environment is finished and then prints them there, so the footnotes aren't being printed until after the longtable is over.